How can I automatically remove all of a single audio track from an MKV and then verify that the audio track has been removed?
This is a bit of a multi-part question, so please bear with me.
My NAS is filling up with TV shows, so for the purposes of saving space, I'm trying to remove all dubbed audio tracks from my multi-audio videos. Currently, my process is as follows:

I use mkvinfo on the first episode of a show to check which tracks I want to keep
Run mkvmerge on all episodes in the directory, only keeping the audio and subtitle tracks that I want (eg. for file in *.mkv; do mkvmerge -o output/$file --audio-tracks 2 --subtitle-tracks 3 --default-track 2 --default-track 3 $file; done)
Manually verify that all the episodes correctly have the audio and sub tracks I want.

For me, this is an extremely tedious process, particularly the manual verification part, as some episodes might switch up the order or add an extra track somewhere. The shows I need to filter through numbers in the thousands, so this process will end up taking potentially days.
Is there any way of automating these processes? One major roadblock I foresee is that tracks are often not properly labelled. I'm considering writing a program to do this for me, but if there's a simpler solution, I would love to know. Thanks.

It looks like ffmpeg can list information on the language of an audio track or subtitle. Perhaps you can use that first to know what index to keep. Eg question

Here's a discussion around filtering in a specific language tag, if that's what you're seeking to do.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71114086/ffmpeg-pick-first-audio-stream-of-specific-language
